# How to send object info in cocos2dJS to android logcat?

Tags: javascript, android, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-js, android-uiautomator

We want to display object info (id,coordinates,tags) in the android logs. Is there there any generic way of displaying the required info in the logs ? Something like extending cclog or adding alternative classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSON.stringify() function to output objects with cc.log. They are shown in the adb logcat output.

```
var obj = {
   id: "foo",
   coords: {
      long: 13.4434343,
      latt: 45.3235698
   }
};

cc.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```